# Got stuck with compiler-gcc6.h when compiling U-Boot for Amlogic

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile the U-boot by using Amlogic's SDK with ./mk g12b_w400_v1 --systemroot  , but got the following errors due to the compiler-gcc6.h not found. The ubuntu environment setup is already followed what the guidance said, now I have no idea how to fix it. Hope someone would know how to fix it, thanks.

> In file included from ../include/linux/compiler.h:54:0,
>                   from ../include/part_efi.h:16,
>                   from ../include/part.h:278,
>                   from ../include/common.h:80:
>   ../include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:114:30: fatal error: >linux/compiler->gcc6.h: No such file or directory
>
> ## include gcc_header(**GNUC**)
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> In file included from ../include/linux/compiler.h:54:0,
>                   from ../include/part_efi.h:16,
>                   from ../include/part.h:278,
>                   from ../include/common.h:80:
>   ../include/linux/compiler-gcc.h:114:30: fatal error: >linux/compiler->gcc6.h: No such file or directory
>
> ## include gcc_header(**GNUC**)